# The add comment link and comment box overlaps bounty box

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, post-notices

The following you could have seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24016296/960757) (sorry, I've commented there, so you won't see it anymore) in Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m (current version). Notice how the **add comment** link overlaps the bounty box:

[image]

The same you can observe with a **comment box** on other sites, e.g. at this time in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/67930/7983):

[image]

Could you shift it a bit down ?

<sup>It seems that it happens on more than just Stack Overflow (maybe all sites ?).</sup>

Comment: It also [happens right here](http://i.imgur.com/UKFpn1a.png) on Meta.SE, and on ServerFault - I'm using Firefox 30 on Windows 7.

Comment: Nice to see that someone *disagree* with my *bug report* even though it clearly happens and it's quite visually annoying.

Comment: @TLama who disagree with you exactly? If you mean André in the above comment he doesn't disagree just telling you it's happening in more sites not just Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Shadow, no, I'm glad for comments from people that tried to reproduce the problem. And sorry, I thought there's a downvote on my Q. My mistake...

Comment: Maybe there was then it was undone. No harm done! :)

Comment: I have revised the report a bit, as you see here when there are comments it's OK, so now focusing on the actual problem which is the "add comment" link.

Comment: @Shadow, actually not. Look at the screenshot in Jonathan's post. The whole comment box overlaps there. I thought the same when I was posting this question on SO meta. But after some investigation I found it's related to the comment box as well (I haven't inspected those elements) and that it happens on many (maybe all) sites.

Comment: Hmm... good point. Rolling back for now better maybe adding this to the question itself?

Comment: @Shadow, thanks! I've included also the comment box screenshot; well, I thought they are closely related (same DOM element ? I haven't inspected them...) so that I posted only comment link screenshot. But it's hard to keep this updated. I was just hoping someone from SE devs will see this and say "we just forgot to move that box when we were moving comments below close reason boxes. will be fixed in...".

Comment: Problem is that all design falls on the shoulders of one developer and looks like he's just too busy. It's annoying, but we can't do anything beyond being patient and nudging the team from time to time by bumping, maybe even emailing sometimes.

Comment: This is essentially same bug as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233470/answer-lock-notice-runs-into-text-below), and the CSS fix described there also fixes this bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, which should be in the next 8 hours.

Comment: O_O? It's the next 6-8 hours?

Comment: Just for that insolence, it will be built out now! :)

Comment: Verified on several sites. Works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is due to some margins on the banners (`.post-notice` class), which actually look horrible on skeptics anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This also occurs on other sites, such as RPG.SE. We only have [one bountied question at the moment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/38275/1204), and it *has* comments, but those comments overlap the box if you mouse over the top one:

[image: a comment overlapping the bounty box]

Comment: Yup, I've noticed that (hence I've moved my Q from SO meta here) and generalized it to comment box from *"add comment"* overlap.